# Probability where one situation increases the likelihood of another

Tags: probability

Probabilities:

I'm trying to built an expert system that can determine the town of an organisation by looking at its webpage.

If there is a lot of data on the page and I find a town's name and I also find a zip code for that town it is very likely that that town is something to do with that organisation.  Say 90% by looking at a large set of data this is the case.

Now, let say that I also look at the domain name of the webpage.  I find that in 70% of cases if the town is mentioned in the domain name "chicagobulls.com" etc.  But quite often it is wrong too say "huffingtonpost.com" which contains the town "Huffington" but doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Now if I find a case where both the town and its zipcode are in the text, AND the word appears in the domain name I'm looking at a very likely situation.  So 90%+ probability.

How to I combine the numbers together to make this happen.

I've tried adding them..  (.9 + .7) / 2  and I've tried multiplying them (.9 * .7) / 2  Neither of which gives me the > 90% result I'm looking for.

I've been Googling around for ages with nothing - maybe my terminology is wrong. Help!

EDIT:

According to the example give [here for soccer](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-events-conditional.html).  There must be something wrong with my calculations since my result comes out at 70%.  I would anticipate getting a higher % probability of a town being in the domain name given that the town was found on the page with a zipcode.  Maybe I'm putting the horse before the cart.  Can you suggest any errors in my calculations?

I've drawn a little diagram in the style of that site:

[image: Conditional Probabilities]

This suggests .63 + .07 = 70% chance that a given a town in the page with a zip code and in the domain name.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Have you heard of Bayesian probability? Conditional probability is *exactly* what you want. You might need to build a database, though.

Comment: No, I stopped math at 16.  Wish I'd carried on now.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Okay that's good. Read the wikipedia page, and comment back here if you need explanation of anything.

Comment: @Sabyasachi OK thanks for the keywords "Conditional Probability" and the heads up.  I been looking some YouTube videos and they all about dice!  I've tried to work through an example copying another example but I'd hope for more than 90%+ gain in information.